# Jimdo - How to pass Conversion Value to Affiliate Network?

Tags: javascript, tracking, google-tag-manager

i have a customer who is using Jimdo, he wants to sell his products via affiliate networks and he wants to share a 30% Commission based on the sales amount.

**The affiliate network provided this pixel:**

```
<iframe src="https://network.com/track?offer_id=123&amount={sale_amount}" height="1" width="1" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I need to figure out how to *pass the final conversion value from Jimdo back to the network*.

**Jimdo Problems:**

1. Due to the HomePage kit, no individual thank you pages pages can be created. There is only one Page /orderconfirmation to add the pixel.
2. That's why I've been looking for a new solution and are currently trying to solve affiliate plans of my customer with the **Google Tag Manager** (GTM).

Now I we have new problems.
 
Typically, with Google Tag Manager you can detect different DataLayers that allow you to work with them. Unfortunately, Jimdo is not really transparent and GTM is not able to capture this DataLayer.

If you check their website structure with your browser, the are actually have all data points.

- Module ID
- List item
- Data-product-id
- Data-variant-id
- Data-product-count
- Data-product-item-id
- Data-product-hash
- Order_tracking_ID

If this cant be done, fine.

Then I just try to determine the code structure of the cart value.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iINOq.png)

I need to know **how to get sales amount value and pass it back to the affiliate network** via Google Tag Manager.

Trigger should be the last button "buy now" before the thank you and on the thank you page the pixel should fire  www.somejimdosite.com/orderconfirmation

Other ideas are welcome!

1. What javascript query could help to solve this problem? (Tag in GTM)

Can this help to get the data?

document.querySelector(".cc-checkout-number span").textContent

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need custom javascript - the DOM type variables can be used to retrieve the text content of a CSS selector (will match the first one it finds, but I assume checkout number will occur only once on the page). You just need to set selection method to "CSS Selector" instead the default  "Id". If you do not enter anything in "Attribute name" the variable will return the textContent.

[image]

And take care that you do not fire your tag on page load - the DOM needs to be there to be scraped, so DOM ready is the earliest moment you can use this